# Moose: builder requires a value that sometimes is not set (non deterministic)

Tags: perl, moose

I'm new to MOOSE and Perl OOP, and I'm struggling understanding the execution order of the code.

I want to create a class reading files, so an attribute of the object should be the filehandle and another the filename to be read.

My problem is that the attribute 'filehandle' has a builder that requires $self->filename, but sometimes at runtime 'filename' is not (yet) available when the builder is called.

Thanks for you help

My ideal object creation:

```perl
my $file = FASTQ::Reader->new(
    filename => "$Bin/test.fastq",
);
```

Perl module:

```perl
has filename => (
    is => 'ro',     isa => 'Str',     required => 1,
);

has fh => (
  is => 'ro',   isa => 'FileHandle',   builder => '_build_file_handler',
);

sub _build_file_handler {
   my ($self) = @_;
   say Dumper $self;
   open(my $fh, "<", $self->filename) or die ("cant open " . $self->filename  . "\n");
   return $fh;
}
```

See: https://gist.github.com/telatin/a81a4097913af55c5b86f9e01a2d89ae

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a value of one attribute depends on another attribute, make it lazy.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package My::Class;
    use Moose;

    has filename => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
    has fh => (is => 'rw', isa => 'FileHandle', lazy => 1, builder => '_build_fh');
    #                                           ~~~~~~~~~

    sub _build_fh {
        my ($self) = @_;
        open my $fh, '<', $self->filename or die $!;
        return $fh
    }
}

my $o = 'My::Class'->new(filename => __FILE__);
print while readline $o->fh;
```

See [Laziness in Moose::Manual::Attributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Attributes#Laziness):

> if the default value for this attribute depends on some other attributes, then the attribute *must* be `lazy`.

Comment: Thanks! When you start with Moose there are so many things that is difficult to get around.

Comment: Now the "builder" subroutine is indeed called after the population of all the attributes, thanks!

My problem is that I defined a method "getline()" in the module, that if invoked like `my $obj = Mod::Reader->new(filename..); $obj->print_line();` results in print_line() invoked _before_ the builder. How can I defer also the execution of object methods (if this is what I should do)?

Comment: A lazy attribute is initialized when it's first needed. Why do you need to initialize it *before* it's needed?

Comment: You're definitely right, I'm missing something _else_. Your implementation works perfectly, as soon as I try to package a module (https://github.com/telatin/FASTQ-Parser/blob/master/lib/FASTQ/Reader.pm) and a script calling it (https://github.com/telatin/FASTQ-Parser/blob/master/scripts/Reader.pl) it stops working: i dont get anything from `readline $o->fh`. Thanks for your help

Comment: Weird, it works for me when I copy your code. The `defined $self->fh` test isn't needed, BTW.

Comment: Thanks! Just to know, which system did you test the two files? I used OS X (perl 5.18) and Ubuntu Linux (perl 5.22).

Comment: I'm using OpenSuse with perl 5.18.2.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and patience: now everything works as expected!